# How i can create json on javascript(jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have json:

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 3,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 3,
    "aaData": [
        ["http://google.com", "0", "0", "2013-02-20 18:31:02"],
        ["http://ya.ru",      "0", "0", "2013-02-22 18:45:43"],
        ["http://yandex.ru",  "0", "0", "2013-02-22 18:45:43"]
    ]
}
```

How i can create same JSON on JavaScript(jQuery)?

ADD

Initially, I have only

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 3,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 3,
    "aaData": []
}
```

In the future i want add data to **"aaData"**...

Sorry, that poorly written question ..

Comment: That is already JSON, which is just a javaScript object. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: HOUSE?! You're a javascript developer?!

Comment: well, to be clear, JSON is not a javascript object, however it can be created from a javascript object or converted to a javascript object. What exactly are you asking? creating the above json with javascript could be as simple as `var jsonString = '... the text from above without linebreaks ...'`;

Comment: @limelights House wouldn't use StackOverflow, unless it were to tell everyone they're wrong.

Comment: We have an impostor in our midst...

Comment: just use var something = what you have written...

Comment: Funny, but but we all have questions, even Dr. House! :D

Comment: JSON is a *string representation* of data, that just so happens to share syntax with JavaScript.  What *exactly* do you have, what *exactly* are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: Ok.. I have data from server and i want edit some data from JSON and use with DataTables.js

Comment: @Nolik: How are are getting the data?  Once you have it as an object, just add to it: `obj.aaData.push(["http://google.com", "0", "0", "2013-02-20 18:31:02"]);`

Comment: @Nolik: JSON is a serialized representation of your data. When that representation is sent to a programming environment (like the web browser), you parse it into the native data structures of that environment. For a browser, it'll be a JavaScript environment with Objects, Arrays and primitive data types like `number`, `string`, etc. So which part are you having trouble with? Have you gotten it parsed? If so, do you know how to manipulate typical JavaScript objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get you, but to create a JSON string out of an object use the [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method like this:

```
var obj = {
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 3,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 3,
    "aaData": [
        ["http://google.com", "0", "0", "2013-02-20 18:31:02"],
        ["http://ya.ru",      "0", "0", "2013-02-22 18:45:43"],
        ["http://yandex.ru",  "0", "0", "2013-02-22 18:45:43"]
    ]
};

var json = JSON.stringify( obj );
```

For the other way around, there is the [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method:

```
var obj = JSON.parse( json );
```

**EDIT**

So assuming you already got this object:

```
var obj = {
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 3,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 3,
    "aaData": []
};
```

You can add data to the `aaData` property by using, e.g., [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
obj['aaData'].push( ["http://google.com", "0", "0", "2013-02-20 18:31:02"] );
obj['aaData'].push( ["http://ya.ru",      "0", "0", "2013-02-22 18:45:43"] );
obj['aaData'].push( ["http://yandex.ru",  "0", "0", "2013-02-22 18:45:43"] );
```